# Why do $pull on MongoDB remove duplicate elements in array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pull

I have the following document in collection:

```
db.test

{
  "_id": ObjectId("55fa5146d39ef1af3fad132b"),
  "member": ["john", "lisa", "kevin", "john"]
}
```

and the following query:

```
db.test.update({}, {$pull:{member:"john"}}
```

run in mongo shell.

then, the following document is result:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55fa5146d39ef1af3fad132b"),
  "member": ["lisa", "kevin"]
}
```

.

Why is removed duplicate element that is "john" in member array.
I am not sure what's causing this problem by $pull.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Because that is what `$pull` does it removes all elements  that match the specified  value. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: So what is your actual question? Remove only the first matched instance of a value from the array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pull one instance of an item in an array in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018889/how-to-pull-one-instance-of-an-item-in-an-array-in-mongodb)