# Pull only one element from and Array in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was trying to pull only one element from an Array which is a mongo document.

My db looks like this:

```
product: ['foo','foo','foo'],
...
```

I want to remove only one element from this array.

My db should Look like this:

```
product: ['foo','foo'],
...
```

When I was using `model.findByIdAndUpdate( id, { $pull: {product: 'foo'} } )`

I loose all my values from `product`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pull one instance of an item in an array in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018889/how-to-pull-one-instance-of-an-item-in-an-array-in-mongodb)

Comment: No, That approach is too old and and those $pop methods are not working now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`

```
doc.findById(productId) 
    .then(async (result) => {
        if (!result) {
            console.log("No Record Found.");
        } else {
            result.index = undefined;
            await result.save();
            console.log('Record Updated Successfully.');
        }
    })
    .catrch(err => {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    });
```

`

You can do this to bring the document and then make the required element as undefined and then you can save the modified document back to the database.

Else you can have a better and optimized approach.

```
`db.doc.update( { _id: 1 }, { $pop: { products: -1 } } )`
```

Here the first element from the product array will be deleted.

**Note**: this is the MongoDB shell syntax.